# Master Theorem,Solving the recurrence , T(n)=3T(n/2)+nlogn

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

T(n) = 3 * T(n / 2) + n * log(n)

Which case should be applied and why? I think case 1 but not sure.

Master Theorem:

[image]

Comment: "Which case?" <-- yes, *which* case? can you provide avalaible choices?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Answer (score 0):

```
T(n) = 3 * T(n / 2) + n * log(n)

a = 3 / b = 2 / f(n) = n log n

n^( log_b(a-ep) ) = n^(log_2(3-ep)) = n^1.58...

f(n) = n log n and is in O(n^1.58) as in case (1)

Therefore, T(n) in Theta(n^1.58...)
```